# Prove that $\sqrt n \log n = O (n)$

Tags: algorithms

Can someone please help me prove this problem? I don't know the right direction to take this problem in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), for any $n\geq 1$

$$ \color{red}{\log n} = \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}\color{red}{\leq} \sqrt{\int_{1}^{n}1\,dx \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^2}} =\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n}-2}=\color{red}{\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$
hence $\log(n)=O(\sqrt{n})$ for $n\to +\infty$, that is enough to prove your claim.

Comment: This is a very neat argument, and I upvoted it for that, but probably not the most natural to suggest to someone starting with this sort of questions. Specifically, I would fear that, when asked to proved now that $\sqrt{n}\log n = O( n^{3/4} )$ (for instance), the OP would not see where to start.

Comment: @ClementC.: you are probably right. To address that concern, I may add that the same approach is able to produce similar inequalities by decomposing $\frac{1}{x}$ as $\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}\cdot\frac{1}{x^{1-\alpha}}$, such that, in general, $$\log(n)=O(n^{\beta})$$ for every $\beta>0$.

Comment: That also follows from the fact that for every polynomial $p(x)$, $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{p(x)}{e^x}=0.$$

Comment: I agree, and again there is nothing wrong with your argument -- the only issue I'd see (I am currently TA-ing an algorithms class, and can see some of the struggle students have with $O(\cdot)$-notations) is that it looks like magic, and is hard to generalize when one is not already familiar enough with such things.

Answer (score 2):

1. Prove that for $n$ "big enough," $\log n \leq \sqrt{n}$.
2. Conclude that for $n$ "big enough," $\sqrt{n}\log n \leq n$.
3. Conclude that $\sqrt{n}\log n = O(n)$.

---

*For 1., an option would be to remember that $\log n = 2\log \sqrt{n}$, and (if you know that limit) that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x} = 0$.*